# Change Stream: Why is FullDocument returned as null?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, changestream

I am using C# driver to get the Change stream. But now I have want to filter the incoming documents. After reading some text and stackoverflow answers I have two ways of doing this. But for some reason one of the way is returning me the FullDocument and other one not.

*I would like to understand why is it so. If someone has encountered or know what is the reason. Please share your comments.*

**Below pipeline works. meaning I could get the Full Document.**

```cs
var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>()
                                    .Match("{ operationType: { $in: [ 'replace', 'insert', 'delete' ] } }")
                                    .Match($@"{{ ""fullDocument.ProcessUniqueId"" : {{ $ne: ""{Constants.UniqueInstanceGuid}"" }} }}");
```

**Below pipeline does not work, meaning I am getting FullDocument as null**

```cs
var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>()
                    .Match(Builders<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>
                        .Filter
                        .In(x => x.OperationType, new List<ChangeStreamOperationType> { ChangeStreamOperationType.Insert, ChangeStreamOperationType.Update, ChangeStreamOperationType.Delete }))
                    .Match(Builders<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>
                        .Filter.Ne(x => x.FullDocument["ProcessUniqueId"], Constants.UniqueInstanceGuid));
```

**And the main loop processing the change stream**

```cs
using (var cursor = await Database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("VERSIONS").WatchAsync(pipeline)) {

                await cursor.ForEachAsync((change) => {

                    Console.WriteLine(change.Id);
                });
}
```